# How to open image url on browser using android widget

Tags: android, android-widget, android-pendingintent

How do i use intent in android widget to open images in browser.

Comment: Intent.Action_view will open a browser but to open a image stored in your app I dont think browser is appropriate app.

Comment: can you please tell Intent for open some article in browser using android widget.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the image is on the internet it would be as simple as this:

```
String url = "http://www.picturesnew.com/media/images/image-background.jpg";
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
startActivity(i);
```

However if the image is inside of your assets you can't open it in the browser. That's because the browser accepts URI data that starts with `http`. Furthermore the browser is a separate app and one app can't use other apps assets.

You could dipslay the image through the use of a WebView though.

Answer (score 0):

To open a website from your widget:

```
Intent intent= new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.fakesite.com\articles"));
startActivity(intent);
```