# any url scheme for chrome to start download

Tags: android, google-chrome

im new so sorry if im asking anything wrong .. i need help in my app .. i want to allow my app users to download my designs . all designs are upload on my site and its like http://exaple.com/design1.jpg

i want to allow users to just click on link and chrome or android default browser (any code if you can provide needed ) open and image will download in users mobile. like whats app url scheme ( whatsapp://send?text= ) and like line ( line://msg/text/ ). any url scheme like chrome://download?file=http://exaple.com/design1.jpg please help me i need url scheme not any android code .. thanks everyone . i hope you understand my question

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with Intents. Like here: [How to open image url on browser using android widget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24968333/how-to-open-image-url-on-browser-using-android-widget) Use an Intent to open an image in the default browser of the device.